In Geometry Nodes, how do I Bend a curve created by the "Curve Line" node?
I have a Curve Line that is converted to points and then the points are used to instance another object.  Now I want to animate the whole object bending and curling.  How do I manipulate the curve?
The issue I'm having is I have already got my scene meticulously set up, and I need to be able to curve the object from exact position of the first anchor point, so that it works with a composite I've built.
Can anyone think of a way that I can make the curve bend and curl from that point?

What about adding animated empty(s) in the scene, retrieve their position with an Object Info node in the GN creating the curve, to move its control points ? You can have them all in a single collection to keep things tidy, if there are many.

What about creating the curve outside of GN, "import" it using an Object Info node inside the GN attached to a single vertex to instance objects ? In this case, control points can be edited in Edit Mode and animated as usual.

The issue I'm having with this is I have already got my scene meticulously set up, and I need to be able to curve the object from exact position of the first anchor point, so that it works with a composite I've built.  Can you think of a way that I can make the curve bend and curl from that point?

Can you manufacture a simplified case with the "first" anchor point, and the curve with its GN modifier attached ? Then could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

@GlenCandle: please add your last comment to your question so that everybody knows what you have and want. thx.

Hey @StefLAncien thank you for the offer but I don't have time to strip the project down to the basics, I would basically have to start a new project but I am on a crunch.

I think you have to make clear  what you want your interface to the curve to be.. is it for animation, or modelling.. what sort of controls you want?

Noise Offset, Scaled by Z
Assuming you want the bending and curling to appear random and organic like the dancing of a flame, or a string blowing in the wind, you could offset the points of your line with a Noise Texture node. To anchor the line as though it is pinned to its origin, scale the noise vector by the Z component of the Position Attribute of the line. This means that as the Position approaches the origin, the offset will approach 0.0, leaving the line in place there. I have assumed that the line starts at the origin and extends one unit along the Z axis. You could animated the W input of the Nose Texture node to make the string dance like a flame.

If you want the string to curl in a more regular way, like the coiling of a snake or a frog rolling up its tongue, You could look up the math for displacing a strait line into a spiral, and then replace the noise setup with the nodes for that spiral math.

Thank you Fletcher, this is what I'm looking for.  And yeah, I will do some math and make a spiral, I just wasn't sure what the node setup would look like.  I think I can take what you did and sneak in my own solution within your framework. Cheers.
